# Keep current SessionWizardView step when switch to another webpage

Tags: python, django, session, caching, django-views

I use SessionWizardView (form-tools) to perform the files process function in Django: uploading-parse-validation-save to finalize steps and I created a threading inside the process_step method. So the files processing will still run and return result when I visit another pages inside the application.
The issue is when I click the link back to the file process page, the processed result is showing current step information but the form and steps jumped to the first step, I know it might be the **init** reset the current view, so I used cache to store steps and get like this:

```
Class myclassview(SessionWizardView):
  #...other settings
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filelist=[]
        self.some_id=None
        self.someLog=None
        if cache.get('process_step')==None:
            cache.set('process_step', 'upload_file')
   def process_step(self, form):
        cache.set('process_step', self.steps.next)
        step=cache.get('process_step')
        print(f"next step: {step}")
        current_step = self.steps.current
        #...
        print(current_step)
        if current_step == 'upload_file':
           #...
            if form.is_valid():
                # some processing in threading,get progress,some log     
            else:
                return render(request, 'template.html', context)

        elif current_step == 'step1': # recheck and save to DB
           # same some processing....
   
                            
        return self.get_form_step_data(form)

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
     
        cache.delete(self.request.session.session_key)
        cache.delete('process_step')
        return redirect(self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])  

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        #set some context...
        return context
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if a step was saved in the cache
        current_step =cache.get('process_step')
        print(f"current_step {current_step}")
        if current_step is not None:
            self.storage.current_step = current_step
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But doesn't work. Anyone know the reason or know how to keep the current step when I switch back? some hints? Thank you!